# Fast sub-image comparison in C#

Tags: c#, image, algorithm, image-processing, bitmap

I'm working on a [photographic mosaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_mosaic) algorithm. There are 4 steps involved:

1. Determine segment regions
2. **Determine cost of each candidate image at each segment region**
3. Determine best assignment of each candidate image to each segment region
4. Render photographic mosaic.

The whole process is relatively straightforward, however Step 2 involves comparing n images with m segments, with n >> m. This is by far the most time intensive step.

Here is the process I go through for each segment-candidate pair:

1. Determine if the candidate image is compatible with the segment dimensions. If not, the assignment is assumed to be forbidden.
2. Using an intermediate sub-picture `Bitmap` created with `Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Rectangle, Rectangle, GraphicsUnit)`, I convert the bitmap data into red, green, and blue `int[,]` matrices for the segment of the original image. I use the `LockBits()` method instead of the `GetPixel()` method as it is vastly faster. To reduce computation time, these matrices are only about 3x3 or 5x5 rather than the full dimensions of the original segment.
3. I do the same process with the candidate image, creating red, green, and blue 3x3 or 5x5 `int[,]` matrices.
4. Starting with `cost = 0`, I add the magnitude of the difference of the red, green, and blue values of the source and candidate image segments to the cost. The sum of these absolute differences is the assignment cost.

In reality, I check each candidate image with all 16 `RotateFlipType` transformations, so there are 16*n*m comparisons needed, where n = the number of segments and m = the number of placement regions.

I'm wondering whether I can perhaps do an FFT of each image and rather than comparing each pixel, I compare the low frequency components only, as the high frequency components will not substantially affect the output. On the other hand a lot of the overhead such as getting the sub-images and converting them to matrices are still there, and my gut tells me a spectral comparison will be slower than basic comparison of 25 `int` values.

Comment: If you do manage to bang out an FFT/DCT at the cost equivalent of 25 integer comparisons, be sure to submit a paper to the relevant journal. ;)

Comment: Here's a couple of questions before I venture an answer. Do you really need to check ALL rotations for the candidate images? You really only want to flip them around the vertical axis, correct? Secondly, what function are you minimizing per segment/candidate? From what I know of these algorithms, you can do it one of two ways - either shrink the segment down to 1 pixel by repeatedly filtering it and then pick candidate images that are the closest match to that color or minimize the difference in color histogram that each candidate would make when substituted for the segment.

Comment: @spender, Of course. I think the **possible** advantage of the FFT approach would be that I could perform it, in O(log_2 n), and can avoid having to resize the original images to 3x3 or 5x5.

Comment: Both these methods don't need you to perform each comparison repeatedly. You can pre-calculate match factors for each segment and candidate and only match per substitution.

Comment: _"**I'm wondering** whether I can perhaps do an FFT of each image and rather than comparing each pixel... On the other hand a lot of the overhead such as getting the sub-images and converting them to matrices are still there, and **my gut tells me** a spectral comparison will be slower than basic comparison of 25 int values"_ - What research have you done?  What have you tried?  Any code to show?  This will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: @ananthonline I'm considering the case where all 16 filps/rotations are available. Yes, I can bring it down to 1x1 but the smaller the comparison matrix the less accurate the matching will be. With a 2x2 I get the edges of the image matched, and with a 3x3 i get the corners, edges, and centre of the images matched. I'm working with 5x5 because it gives much better matching for not much more computation.

Comment: @MickyDuncan My experience with FFTs is limited to identifying and manipulating dominant frequencies over the whole domain. I could do the naive method of splitting each segment up into 3x3 or 5x5 sub-segments and comparing the dominant frequencies for those. Otherwise, I'm not sure how to identify the frequency components in parts of the image or if it's even practically possible.

Comment: Fair enough. So let's leave that method out. However, do you really want to compare edges between candidates? You'll get very similar images grouped together in areas of gradual change. I'd recommend a method that performs energy minimization using a heuristic (histogram)? This will allow more candidates to match a segment and not cluster similar images.

Comment: I would have thought a **RGB mean** be sufficient rather than resorting to a FFT. In the paper _"Fast Photomosaic"_ by Gianpiero Di Blasi and Maria Petralia; - University of Catania, Italy; they state _"The photomosaic creation is very simple and easy to
explain in few steps. First we subdivide the input
image into a regular grid, then each cell of the grid
into another 3x3 sub-grid. Second we compute the
RGB mean values for each sub-cell of the sub-grid.
This leads us to a vector x composed by 27
components (three RGB components for each subcell).
x is the feature vector of the cell."_

Comment: @MickyDuncan This is essentially quite similar to what I'm already doing. I'm using totals instead of means. The bottleneck is probably with resizing the images. If I work out the average RGB values of the 3x3 sub-grid from the full bitmap data and avoid resizing altogether it may be faster (I'll try it tonight), but my candidate images are quite large: about 18 million pixels; that's why I didn't even try this method to begin with.

Comment: @MickyDuncan I just threw together a quick test. Two functions to return 3x3 matrices of images (http://pastebin.com/LC8Q7izV). The first method creates a temporary 3x3 image, draws on that using `Graphics` and samples that. The second method averages the full image directly. The first method, which is what I'm already using in my current mosaic implementation, is much faster for a 12 megapixel image. 119ms versus 18911ms.

Comment: @Ozzah Yes I like your first option.  Also check out _[How to: Use Interpolation Mode to Control Image Quality During Scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0fsyd4e(v=vs.110).aspx)_.   Though for a 3x3 probably not useful ;)

Comment: @MickyDuncan I set InterpolationMode to NearestNeighbour. There is no significant performance increase. At least nowhere near the magnitude I was expecting. AndreaMosaic scans thousands of sample images in a few seconds while mine takes days. Though, I can guarantee mine produces the most accurate comparison and optimal assignment and I'm not sure AndreaMosaic can make the same claim.

Answer (score 2):

At first I would do a huge speed up by

1. **create info for each image like:**

   average color, r/g/b histograms I think 8 or 16 points per channel will suffice. You can add any other info (darkest/brightest color,...) but it should be rotation/flip invariant
2. **index sort the images by average color**

   limit the R,G,B to few bits only like 4 ... and create single integer number from it  like

   ```
   col=R+(G<<4)+(B<<8);
   ```

   and finally **index sort** used images by this number
3. **comparison**

   so **binary search** the index sorted images (if you create table of indexes per each reduced color then this will be also reduced to `O(1)`) and find only images with close or equal average color as your segment.

   Then find closest matches to histogram from these and then apply all you have only on those images...

   The histogram comparison can be done by correlation coefficient or by any distance,or statistical deviation ...

   As for the **FFT** part of your question I think it is more or less already answered by comments. Yes you can use it but I think it is an overkill for this. The overhead is huge but you can rescale images to low resolution and use **FFT** on that or just compare low res images only instead

**[Notes]**

Also using **HSV** instead of **RGB** could improve visual similarity